# NGINX Custom error 500 page is not showing

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I'm trying to catch the error 500 that NGINX shows when the `/` location doesn't exist or is empty.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/app;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      ssi on;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      internal;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

When I save and test this, NGINX tells me the configuration is valid.
But then when I clear my dist folder, I get the default NGINX error 500.

`ls -l` of `/usr/share/nginx/html/`

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root root     43 Feb 17 15:26 50x.html
drwxrwxrwx   2 root root   4096 Feb 17 15:32 dist
```

How is it that I still get the error 500 from NGINX, instead of the 50x.html doc?

Answer (score 4):

change your nginx configs to

```
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    server_name  localhost;
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/app;
    index  index.html index.htm;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      ssi on;
      root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
      index 50x.html
      internal;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =500;
    }
}
```

and you will be able to see the custom error

```
➜  ~   curl http://127.0.0.1:32769/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Error</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>This is My custome error.</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

basically you need to add the index to the error location

```
 index 50x.html
```

and throw an error if none of the files exists

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =500;
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `/index.html` is something that runs interpreted (e.g. PHP-FPM), NGINX will default to showing errors from FastCGI server.

To deliver errors by NGINX, you would want to use [`fastcgi_intercept_errors`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_intercept_errors):

```
fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
```

Similiarly, if you're proxying request to `/index.html` elsewhere (other than a FastCGI server), you would use [`proxy_intercept_errors`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_intercept_errors):

```
proxy_intercept_errors off;
```

Comment: Nope, It's an angular application. There's no CGI backend nor a reverse proxy.